# apt doesn't work on kali linux 2020.3

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [16.6 MB]
Err:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                          
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:16634563 [weak]
   - SHA256:fbb326970ca4e9cdb4fef1aa9a8be44356dc8d9fdab37069e9a19e65ee3ae952
   - SHA1:cea7b3e7681b2f1a8070ea788ad7779e5f178fb3 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e6fc65db75d4b81ea72b4f35e18d3b18 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:a2b234d6a45e017ca97ce9d720a0ca4f79fe6b4956692bef2864e75d845291bc
   - SHA1:e7e682ffe978727c54f671b2424df435b48c26ca [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e6fc65db75d4b81ea72b4f35e18d3b18 [weak]
   - Filesize:16634563 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 12:07:19 +0000
  Release file created at: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 12:08:13 +0000
Get:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages [100 kB]                                                                                                                                                              
Get:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages [100 kB]                                                                                                                                                              
Fetched 16.8 MB in 14s (1,219 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://kali.download/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:16634563 [weak]
    - SHA256:fbb326970ca4e9cdb4fef1aa9a8be44356dc8d9fdab37069e9a19e65ee3ae952
    - SHA1:cea7b3e7681b2f1a8070ea788ad7779e5f178fb3 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e6fc65db75d4b81ea72b4f35e18d3b18 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:a2b234d6a45e017ca97ce9d720a0ca4f79fe6b4956692bef2864e75d845291bc
    - SHA1:e7e682ffe978727c54f671b2424df435b48c26ca [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e6fc65db75d4b81ea72b4f35e18d3b18 [weak]
    - Filesize:16634563 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 12:07:19 +0000
   Release file created at: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 12:08:13 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The os is kali linux version 2020.3 . I just installed the operating system on virtualbox but when I use apt to install any package it doesn’t work and it gives me "Unable to locate packege". So I tried to use apt update but the result is the one above. can you help me to re-call apt?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `sudo service ntp restart`